# Finding the Java actual stack trace from a javascript stack trace

Tags: gwt

We have implemented a general mechanism that logs on the server exceptions from the GWT client side.
Naturally, some of them are unexpected exceptions (such as NPE), and therefore we are getting kind of these stack traces in our log (an excerpt):

```
java.lang.Throwable: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
        at Unknown.Hq(Unknown Source)
        at Unknown.ihb(Unknown Source)
        at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
        at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
        at Unknown.anonymous(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: (TypeError): d is null
stack: EG([object Object],[object Object])@http://domain/path/0B15791BA99231E6B88EAF3BDE38EB64.cache.html:3282

fileName: http://domain/path/0B15791BA99231E6B88EAF3BDE38EB64.cache.html
lineNumber: 3282
        at Unknown.EG(Unknown Source)
        at Unknown.DG(Unknown Source)
```

How can I find the class and line number in the original java source?

I don't want to deploy a detailed compiled version, since I don't have information about the exact scenario and I can't reproduce the exception.

Comment: So does that mean that you need to subclass the logger for every module and set the location explicitly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GWT compiler outputs the mapping in symbolMap files in the `-deploy` and `-extra` locations (where `-deploy` defaults to the `-war`'s `WEB-INF/deploy`, and `-extra` is not emitted by default).
I use it *manually* to debug weird things from time to time.

You can also deobfuscate traces programmatically, using the [`StackTraceDeobfuscator`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/logging/server/StackTraceDeobfuscator.html).
FYI, this class is used by the [`RemoteLoggingServiceImpl`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/logging/server/RemoteLoggingServiceImpl.html) GWT-RPC servlet and the [`Logging`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/server/Logging.html) RequestFactory service; respectively called by the [`SimpleRemoteLogHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/logging/client/SimpleRemoteLogHandler.html) and [`RequestFactoryLogHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/gwt/client/RequestFactoryLogHandler.html) (they're `java.util.logging.LogHandler`s which you can use with the [logging API](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Remote_Logging) that GWT supports). In this case, it looks into the `WEB-INF/deploy` of the webapp (which is why `-deploy` defaults there).

Comment: I did the following:
1. Added <set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated"/> at the module xml file.

Comment: 2. Override RemoteLoggingServiceImpl and call to setSymbolMapsDirectory("WEB-INF/deploy/{Modulename}/symbolMaps/").

Comment: Although it was in the documentation, didn't have to add the -extra option. At least, I didn't see any difference when I added it.

Comment: Now the log stack trace shows the java class names, still without line numbers. I guess the deobfuscator just replaces the symbols using the symbol map but it can't find the exact line numbers.

Comment: 3. For some reason I had to call to logger at the module onLoad, to have later any real log error at the server, I added this:
Logger.getLogger("").finest("Dummy text")

Comment: Yes, it's only precise at the method level. Source Maps have been added recently but haven't yet made it into a release. See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SourceMaps