# Original Java Stack Trace from GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, stack-trace

Is it possible for GWT to give the stack trace for the original Java code after a crash, as opposed to the JS stack trace?

I'm using Chrome 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what browser you're using at the time of the crash, but GWT has built functinality for [emulating Java stack traces](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions). Make sure you are compiling and implementing the symbolmap files in your war directory with your cache js files.

Another option is to compile with the output style set to "Detailed", and then looking at the raw javascript in any standard browser javascript console will point you to the right place in your Java code, as nearly every line in the javascript refers to a fully-qualified class name and method.

Comment: "Make sure you are compiling and implementing the symbolmap files in your war directory with your cache js files." How do I do that?

Comment: in your war/WEB-INF/deploy/<projectname>/symbolMaps/ directory, you should see a bunch of *.symbolMap files with long hash-value names. Make sure the names of these files correspond to the names of the *.cache.html files in your war/<projectname>/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the original stacktrace but you have to perform [Deobfuscation](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions#Resymbolization_/_Deobfuscation)

Answer (score 0):

We had [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804434/finding-the-java-actual-stack-trace-from-a-javascript-stack-trace) issue. It works fine, and with latest GWT version even shows line numbers.
Notice to my comments for Thomas Broyer answer.